# pssh with ssh ProxyJump with multiplexing session re-use

Tags: ssh, bastion, multiplexing

I have a list of nodes, that are accessible only through a bastion server.
On these nodes, I would like to execute commands in parallel. So, I had been trying to use ssh `-J` flag or, respectively, the ssh_config `ProxyJump` option in combination with parallel ssh `pssh`.

To speed up re-connections, I am using ssh multiplexing

```
 ControlMaster auto
 ControlPersist 60m
 ControlPath /tmp/ssh-%i@%l_%r@%h:%p
```

However, something like

```
pssh -O ProxyJump=USERNAME@bastion.fqdn -p 5 -l root -h /tmp/nodes.lst 'echo $HOSTNAME'
```

fails and runs into timeouts.

Hard-wiring the node list in the ssh config is not really feasible, so that I am depending on a commandline compatible solution.